# big double square brackets

Tags: scaling, stmaryrd

I'm trying to get the double square brackets from the `stmaryrd` package printed big, following [this post](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=21408) with no success.

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table}, fleqn]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \[
  \bigl\llbracket \frac{1}{2} \bigr\rrbracket 
  \]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The MWE above still prints them small, so I'm wondering what I'm missing.

[image]

Comment: There are four steps: `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg` and `\Bigg`. Or `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: `\big` is just somewhat larger than normal. They _are_ bigger, try it without `\bigl`. For a fraction you might want `\biggl`.

Comment: You can alos obtain the same result without downloading any font with   \[
 \left[\hspace{-.25cm}\left[\, \frac{1}{2} \, \right]\hspace{-.25cm}\right] 
  \]

Comment: @campa that worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work: perhaps you just want bigger sizes using `\Bigl...\Bigr` etc:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table}, fleqn]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \[
  \bigl\llbracket \frac{1}{2} \bigr\rrbracket
  \Bigl\llbracket \frac{1}{2} \Bigr\rrbracket
  \biggl\llbracket \frac{1}{2} \biggr\rrbracket
  \Biggl\llbracket \frac{1}{2} \Biggr\rrbracket
  \]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```